# 特定文字列を含む括弧で囲まれた文字列以外を正規表現マッチする書き方

Tags: php, 正規表現

以下文章があった場合、`[switch]`以外にマッチする正規表現の書き方を教えてください。

`こんにちわ。[feedback]おはよう。[switch]ありがとうございました。`

追記：
画像の`[feedback]`にもマッチさせたい。(方法としては[switch]以外にマッチさせたいという意味です。

[image: 追記：画像の[feedback]にもマッチさせたい。(方法としては[switch]以外にマッチさせたいという意味です。)]

Comment: 使用している言語はなんでしょうか?

Comment: マッチさせることは目的ではなく、マッチさせた結果を次の処理で使うものと思われます。であればどのような結果が必要なのかを明記してください。現状の質問文では推測は難しいですが、 **[switch]以外にマッチする** とは正規表現を使わずとも単純な文字列一致を行い、オフセット値を用いて処理すれば十分なように見受けられます。

Comment: サンプルとして「マッチする文字列」「マッチしない文字列」の二通り(+α)あった方が正規表現の話をする場合は意図が伝わりやすいと思います。

Comment: 質問文が間違っていませんか？ 「特定文字列を含む括弧で囲まれた文字列以外をする」「[switch]以外にマッチする」と書かれていますが、「[feedback]にもマッチさせたい」とも書かれています。PHPのようですので`strstr`で`[switch]`にマッチさせればそれまでではありませんか？

Comment: `[switch]`を削るだけではだめなのでしょうか。

Comment: 例えば、入力文が `[switch]こんにちわ。[feedback]おはよう。[switch]ありがとうございました。[switch]` の場合は全ての `[switch]` を除外するという事でしょうか？

Comment: sayuriさん：[switch]以外にマッチさせたいという状況です。

Comment: cubickさん：はい。その書き方を知りたく。。

Comment: metropolisさん：はい。その通りです。

Comment: PHP でしたら、[PHP str_replace() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp) を使うと良いかと。

Comment: 確認ですが 使用言語は PHP でよろしいですか？ （スクリーンショットからそう推測されています）

Comment: mjyさん：はい。そうです。

Answer (score 1):

#### 正規表現にマッチする部分を削除する

「正規表現のパターンにマッチする部分以外を取り出す」のは「正規表現のパターンにマッチする部分を削除する」ことで実現できます。
[`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.preg-replace.php) を用いて、空文字に置換すればよいです。

```
<?php
$str = '[switch]今日は。[feedback]おはよう。[switch]ありがとうございました。';
$new_str = preg_replace('/\[switch\]/', '', $str);
echo "$new_str\n";
```

出力:

```
今日は。[feedback]おはよう。ありがとうございました。
```

#### 文字列に一致する部分を削除する

metropolisさんのコメントで指摘されているのは、この例の場合は削除したい文字列は固定的で `[switch]` と決まっていますので、正規表現を使う必要がないということです。
[`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.str-replace.php) を使って、

```
$new_str = str_replace('[switch]', '', $str);
```

のようにすれば十分です。

Answer (score 0):

[switch]とそれ以外の部分を分けるということでしたら、以下のではいかがしょうか？
$1(ないしは\1)と$2(\2)にそれぞれ、”こんにちわ。[feedback]おはよう。”と”ありがとうございました。”が格納されます。

`(.*)\[switch\](.*)`

題意を間違えていたらごめんなさい。

Comment: ありがとうございます。分けるのではなく、[switch]以外にマッチさせたいのです。

Answer (score 0):

例えば

- 頭 `^, \A`
- 尻 `$, \z`
- `[switch]` の頭 `(?=\[switch\])`
- `[switch]` の尻 `(?<=\[switch\])`

として

- 文字列の頭から `[switch]` の頭まで `^(.*?)(?=\[switch\])`
- `[switch]` の尻から `[switch]` の頭まで `(?<=\[switch\])(.*?)(?=\[switch\])`
- `[switch]` の尻から文字列の尻まで `(?<=\[switch\])(.*?)$`

を `|` でつなげばいいのでは？

`(?:^(.*?)(?=\[switch\]))|(?:(?<=\[switch\])(.*?)(?=\[switch\]))|(?:(?<=\[switch\])(.*?)$)`

`^$` が適切か `\A\z` が適切かは場合によるので別途調整してください。

---

追記

文字列の頭、または `[switch]` の尻から `(?:^|(?<=\[switch\]))`
文字列の尻、または `[switch]` の頭まで `(?:(?=\[switch\])|$)`
って考え方でもっと単純になるかもしれません。

`(?:^|(?<=\[switch\]))(.*?)(?:(?=\[switch\])|$)`

ご参考まで。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決に近づきました。
例えば”[switch~~~~~~]"
（~は任意の文字列文字数も任意）
となった場合はどのように記述できるのでしょうか。

Comment: お使いの正規表現エンジンが先読み時の条件に量指定子を利用できる場合 `\[switch\]` を `\[switch[^\]]*\]` に変えるだけのはずです（たぶん）。
指定できない場合、私では適当な正規表現を思いつけません。 （ `sayuri` さんと同じ様な回答になりますが）マッチさせた後何がしたいかなどをお伝えいただければ力になれるかも知れません。 
勝手に状況を想像しますが、単に `[switch...]` を含まない文字列（の配列）がほしいなら、例えば `preg_split` を使うことができます。
https://3v4l.org/1P24v